# How to organize array of objects into themselves by id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. Those objects can be root or list element (elements of a tree structure). How can I loop through that array to organize those elements into a tree (objects have property of their parent element - id) with the depth of n (not known)?

I'm trying to build (menu). I have successfully organized list elements into their parents. But I'm stuck at putting all root elements into their parents (or root). Problem that I'm having is doing it without nesting loops (checking when everything is organized).

Example of starting data: https://pastebin.com/eCSZ1HgR

```
[
    {
     "groupId": 1,
     "parentGroupId": null
    },
    {
     "groupId": 3,
     "parentGroupId": 1
    }, ...
]
```

If objects parentGroupId is null, means that it's in the root of a tree.

Currently I'm working with this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  var childGroup = groups[i];

  if (childGroup.parentGroupId === null) {
    continue;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
    var parentGroup = groups[j];

    if (childGroup.parentGroupId === parentGroup.groupId) {
      if (parentGroup.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        parentGroup.children.push(childGroup);
      } else {
        parentGroup.children = [childGroup];
      }

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: What should your resultant array look like?

Comment: Two hints: 1) You only need to make sure that each object is added to its parent's children. You only need to loop the original array once. 2) An easy way of finding an object with a specific id (no looping) is first to build an object mapping id => object (an index).

Comment: @ShubhamJain result should be organized array (each object inside its parent)

Comment: There is a closing curly bracket missing before line 13 in your pasbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) and [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) functions

```
const tree = groups.reduce((acc, group) => {
  group.children = groups.filter(g => g.parentGroupId === group.groupId);
  acc.push(group);
  return acc;
}, []).filter(g => g.parentGroupId === null);
```

Comment: this solution may not handle nested groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that does a deep-copy:

```
const testInput = [
    {
     "groupId": 1,
     "parentGroupId": null
    },
    {
     "groupId": 3,
     "parentGroupId": 1
    },
    {
      "groupId": 4,
      "parentGroupId": 3
    },
    {
      "groupId": 5,
      "parentGroupId": 1
    }
];

function flatToTree(flatList, idPropName, parentPropName, childrenPropName) {

    const list = [];
    const listIndex = {};

    /* Copy the array and create an index */

    flatList.forEach(listItem => {
      const objectCopy = Object.assign({}, listItem);
      list.push(objectCopy);
      listIndex[listItem[idPropName]] = objectCopy;
    });

    /* Assign children */

    list.forEach(listItem => {
      if (listItem[parentPropName]) {
        const parent = listIndex[listItem[parentPropName]];
        if (Array.isArray(parent[childrenPropName])) {
          parent[childrenPropName].push(listItem);
        }
        else {
          parent[childrenPropName] = [listItem];
        }
      }
    });

    /* Pick the root elements */

    return list.filter(listItem => listItem[parentPropName] === null);
}

const testOutput = flatToTree(testInput, "groupId", "parentGroupId", "children");
```